# Laravel 5.2.* redirect->back->with doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, parameters

I want to write some data to my database, if the query fails I want to display an error.
I tried the following:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('data', ['Database Error!']);
```

The redirect works great, but I cant read out the response in $data

My Blade:

```
@if (session()->has('data'))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">...</div>
@endif

//Second try
<?php if(session('data')) echo $message; ?>
```

But both methods doesn't work, i read a lot of L5.2 Docs but nothing works.

Do i need to modify the session config?!?
Or what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried `back()` on its own rather than `redirect()->back()`?

Comment: also found this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects):
"make sure the route using the back function is using the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied"

Comment: "make sure the route using the back function is using the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied"

This is my problem, i fix it tomorrow and report if it's work.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a breaking problem with the 5.2 upgrade. What's happening is the middleware which is responsible for display the `Session` message in all your views is not being utilized because it was moved from the global middleware to the `web` middleware group.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. In your `kernel.php` file(app/Http/Kernel.php), you can move the `middleware \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` back to the `protected $middleware` property.
2. Wrap all your `web` routes with a route group and apply the web middleware to them:

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
       // Place all your web routes here...(Cut all `Route` which are define in `Route file`, paste here) 
   });
   ```

Comment: I choosed the second way, i placed all my web routes in a route-group and it works fine.
Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

try 
`return back()->with('data', ['Database Error!']);`

`back()` will take you to the previous page with a data variable that holds 'Database Error!'

Comment: I think the problem is the missing middleware group.
The back->with() function doesn't work out-of-the-box in my case.

I report the solution code tomorrow.

Comment: Please add more details to explain your answer more. Also, is this `->->` a typo?